# How to fix Xamarin ios App crashes with no logs?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have been trying, to run my app but I get this warning 'Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     [xma]: Failed to execute 'which mono64': ExitStatus = 1 helloMobile.iOS and also on the output has the following message This debug engine does not support exception conditions. The condition(s) will be ignored.' I am trying to run the app via the simulator on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failed to execute 'which mono64': ExitStatus = 1

I met the same issue before, the reason it that I have updated the version of **Xcode** and **Xamarin.iOS** to the latest. **However**, the version of visual studio is not the latest.

**Generally**, if Xcode publish important version update and you update the Xcode and Xamarin.iOS, you also need to update the Visual Studio to keep their versions in sync.

Threrefore, you could have a check with the version of ***Visual Stuido , Xcode, MacOS and Xamarin.iOS*** first. And make them be the latest version to check whether it works.

Last, there is [a solution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1150622/failed-to-execute-which-mono64-exitstatus-1.html) to about this similar problem, you also could have a look.